# Magento Category, Category products pager drop shows ALL

Tags: magento, dropdown

Magento Category, Category products pager drop shows ALL in DEV site and not in local.

Codes are identical. Any clue on this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what version of magento are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: sure. I will post this on magento section